# navbar jumps in google chrome windows 7

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have recently built a site for a friend of mine to showcase the cars he`s built.
The site works fine in ie, opera and even on an iphone. 
However in windows 7 chrome (it works fine in xp) the navbar jumps below header and back to normal when you start clicking through the pages. Here is a link to the site [doa customs](http://www.doacustoms.co.uk).

I am fairly green to coding and am only familiar with html and css basics. I have tried changing the percent values, floating and have added an extra div with an inline property but no joy.

I have ironed out most of the faults but his issue is driving me nuts.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that the navbar goes below the header when the browser window is narrow?

Comment: Hi, no it happens when I first go to the website. After a click to the other pages, even the homepage. It goes back to where it should be. I have fixed it now but I dont know how I did it!!! I think it is to do with the inline property in the "header" div and the "navbar" and the way I set out the margins/padding. I also get the same problem on my other site www.therockscleaning.co.uk but I am currently recoding and testing it to find out why. I will post results when (if) I figure it out.

Comment: For future questions like this, you will get a better response if you can include in your question a minimal amount of code that people can use to recreate the problem, and ideally a link to http://jsfiddle.net with the code. That way questions and answers provide a useful archive for future visitors; if they are links to real sites, the questions stop being useful as soon as the linked sites change.